# What is the best way to iterate properties inside a JavaScript Object?

Tags: javascript

I have the following javaScript object:

```
var theData = {
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Event1",
         "start_time": "2015-01-15T22:00:00-0200",
         "end_time": "2015-01-16T07:00:00-0200",
         "timezone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
         "location": "Somewhere",
         "id": "824583590897935"
      },
      {
         "name": "Event2",
         "start_time": "2015-01-14T22:00:00-0200",
         "timezone": "America/Sao_Paulo",
         "location": "Somewhere",
         "id": "1522505051359796"
      }
   ],
   "paging": {
      "cursors": {
         "after": "MzA0MjY5OTI5NzgwODIz",
         "before": "ODI0NTgzNTkwODk3OTM1"
      },
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/217733628398158/events?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAAW4SjUBnZB9x1Y6euJS6Bbmky2ZBfyMJ7eq4hPyy0g6lrk9itZCS2Rf2vmAmlYS6qcwIBLVs8Vm5ZBnDYbW7ldni3LdmwAqrZAjVXQrloT0nunu6brW21tBzRXyZAyLR7L2oaF14cmusoXzndsadsakvsZyAYSkjQ52g57BW3VqbAHEMQnTtq5uYb4NOHN5xa1IvdecZCgSHNHzKPWYq1VsWZB7qvQgHXvoRAZD&limit=25&after=MzA0MjY5OTI5NzgwODIz"
   }
}
```

So i want to iterate over this object. 
I have the following code that is working. But I'm new to Javascrip and this way i'm doing is a high complexity way. How could i do it as simple as possible once this will be called for a huge amount of times?

```
for (var key in theData) {
   var obj = theData[key];
   for (var prop in obj) {
      var eventObj = obj[prop];
      for (var attribute in eventObj){
         if(eventObj.hasOwnProperty(attribute)){
            console.log(attribute + " = " + eventObj[attribute]);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `paging` is an object?

Comment: It doesn't get any more efficient than that.

Comment: @abhitalks yes. paging is an object too.

Comment: try exploring functions like forOwn in the lodash library. https://lodash.com/docs#forOwn

Comment: It looks ok, what you can do to improve performance and do it more generic is a recursive call to iterate through all your child objects, and the child of your child, etc.

Comment: Don't use `for..in` on arrays. Also, why the `.hasOwnProperty()` check only on the innermost loop?

Comment: @nnnnnn What do u suggest? ... And, i'm just showing the code simplified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Object.keys`:

```
Object.keys(httpResponse).forEach(function (key) {
    console.log(key + ' = ' + httpResponse.data[key]);
});
```

Its more easy to implement and its also more readable.

For your code, you can use something like this:

```
function scan(obj, root) {
    root = root || '';
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (key) {
        if (typeof(obj[key]) === 'object') {
            scan(obj[key], root + key + '.');
        }
        else {
            console.log(root + key + ' = ' + obj[key]);
        }
    });
}

scan(httpResponse);
```

Here you have [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bc5fv17v/) showing the example above working.

If you need to support IE < 9, you may need to use [a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill).

Comment: Please note Object.keys is only supported for IE >= 9, [link to polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)